# Error: Array size mismatch in modification of vessel_ps_static, expected size is [0] and size of binding expression is scalar- Modelica

Tags: modelica

when I specify static pressure in a tank, I face with this error: Array size mismatch in modification of vessel_ps_static, expected size is [0] and size of binding expression is scalar. Does anybody have an idea about this error? Thanks.

```
Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank (vessel_ps_static = 400000, height =1,crossArea =10,portsData = false, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.OpenTank tank1 (vessel_ps_static = 50000000, height =1,crossArea =10,portsData = false, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
```

Comment: `vessel_ps_static` is a vector, but you assign a scalar. As this variable is not a parameter, are you sure that you want to modify it?

Comment: I modify it as I want to specify the pressure values at which low pressure valve and high pressure valve operate. I thought that I can specify these pressure values by connecting tanks.

Comment: But there is already an equation in `OpenTank` to compute `vessel_ps_static`. It don't know the tank model very well, but it looks like you should not set this variable.

Comment: Then which component can be used instead of Opentank to specify operating pressure of valves?

Comment: Maybe the inlet and outlet ports are what you want, which are parametrized via `portsData`. Have a look at the tanks in `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks`. Or you add valves from `Modelica.Fluid.Valves`.

Comment: I added valves already. Can I specifiy pressure value directly in the valve? I thought that I need an opentank for it.

Comment: Comments are not for chit-chat and I am not the right person to help with fluid topics. From my point of view your original question is solved, so you might create a follow-up question.

Comment: I'm not a fluid specialist as well, but to my understanding an open tank needs the respective amount of fluid in the tank to result in a certain pressure. So I would rather try to set `level_start` in the tank (from the Initialization tab) than `vessel_ps_static` (a variable computed in the model, not exposed to the user). Besides that: For 50000000pa (in your tank1) that would be a tank of approx. 5km height (assuming water in the tank).